# How to list folder contents - Get file names in folder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, directory

I am using AIR for andriod and I want to get all the jpg's (or Mp3's) in a folder of an external folder. It will be stored on the users phone and included in the app.

How can I do that from FLASH using Action-script 3?

**Update:**

[This](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) is indeed the correct link for help but how do I write an array that would read through and get all the files in a folder?

Answer (score 4):

Please verify if you are or aren't using AIR, is this an app built to run natively using AIR or is this a web browser based flash content on mobile.  If the former you basically can use the File to resolve the path, then you can use FileStream to read/write files.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html

If the case is the latter, you're not going to have privileges to access the local file system from within the browser.

Comment: Upvoted for adding the specific references. I should have done that before.

Answer (score 2):

With pure flash and AS3 without any PHP/XML or without AIR this is not possible. You can look into [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class but I don't think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: He did say it was for a Droid App, so presumably, he is using AIR to export to the Android platform.

Comment: @meddlingwithfire, sorry, I'm not expert of Android, so I don't know whether AIR is needed for that or not. OP said pure flash, he didn't mention AIR. So my answer is NO if that is pure flash, and YES if AIR is allowed.

Comment: Yes, the question is a little ambiguous.  I think your answer handles either scenario though.

Comment: YES I AM USING ANDROID. I WANT TO BE ABLE TO READ CONTENTS ON THE LOCAL USERS PHONE USING AIR FOR ANDROID.

Comment: @Papa De Beau, why are you shouting? Flash and AIR are not same. Why do you think that everyone who knows flash, AS3 also knows that AIR is used for android? And for answering your question, have you checked the answer provided by shaunhusain? Have you checked the classes that he mentioned? Are they working? If not, what problem you are facing with those classes?

Comment: Sorry I was on my phone and the caps was stuck on. I updated my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was just researching the same thing. This worked well for me: http://snipplr.com/view/25109/

Answer (score -2):

If I understood correctly, you need to copy the pics/mp3s when the app is installed so that you can access them. You can go to file>publish settings and press the wrench next to the player (which should be set to air 2.5). In the "general" tab at the bottom you can add the files or folders that your app will be using. Hope this helps.